# Why aren't these arrays of structs printing anything?

Tags: c++

I have a struct with two arrays in them. I am trying to print out the contents of each array, but when I do all I get is nothing for the string and a zero for the float no matter which element I print.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct menuItem
{
    string breakfastItem[7];
    float itemPrice[7];
}dish;

void setMenu()
{
    dish.breakfastItem[0]= "Plain Eggs";
    dish.itemPrice[0]= 1.45;
    dish.breakfastItem[1]= "Bacon and Eggs";
    dish.itemPrice[1]=2.45;
    dish.breakfastItem[2]="Muffin";
    dish.itemPrice[2]=0.99;
    dish.breakfastItem[3]="French Toast";
    dish.itemPrice[3]=1.99;
    dish.breakfastItem[4]="Fruit Basket";
    dish.itemPrice [4]=2.46;
    dish.breakfastItem[5]="Cereal";
    dish.itemPrice[5]=0.69;
    dish.breakfastItem[6]= "Coffee";
    dish.itemPrice[6]=.50;
    dish.breakfastItem[7]="Tea";
    dish.itemPrice[7]=0.75;
}

int main()
{
    cout << dish.breakfastItem[0];
    cout << dish.itemPrice[0];
}
```

Comment: You should flush (assumed you're debugging and have a breakpoint at the last closing brace in main): `cout << dish.breakfastItem[0] << endl;`

Comment: Do you ever call the `setMenu()` function?

Answer (score 2):

First in order for the code in `setMenu()` to run you need to call the function.

```
int main()
{
    setMenu();
    cout << dish.breakfastItem[0];
    cout << dish.itemPrice[0];
}
```

Secondly

```
dish.breakfastItem[7]="Tea";
dish.itemPrice[7]=0.75;
```

Is undefined behavior as you are writing on past then of the array.  An array of size 7 has the indexes in the range of [0, 6]

Comment: struct 'menuItem' has no member named 'setMenu' is the error I get when I use your first code.  And for the undefined behavior I have 8 menu items...doesn't that mean since the array starts at 0 and goes to 7, i have 8 ordinals?

Comment: @Scotchdew I fixed the code.  With your indentation I thought `setMenu()` was a part of `menuItem`.  You do not have 8 items.  in `menuItem you have `string breakfastItem[7];` which creates an array of 7 items.  If you want 8 then you need to have `string breakfastItem[8];`

Comment: Oh!! It works!! Thanks so much! I see exactly what you mean! It was crashing although I wrote the code correctly except for the number of ordinals in the array. Thanks again! You're the man!